# Unable to resolve host "maps.googleapis.com": in Google Elevation API for android

Tags: android, exception, httpurlconnection

I've developed an application to parse point KML files and get their elevation from Google Elevation API. My problem is that when the application is running and then turn on the network of the device, it throws the Unable to resolve host "maps.googleapis.com", But when I turn on the network before running the application, it returns elevation of points from host service. Below is the snippet for connecting to URL and get data as string:

```
public class HttpManager{

  public static String getData(String uri) {

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        connection.disconnect();
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The JSON result will be parsed in another class to get the elevation. What is the reason of this execption? 
Some tips I want to mention:

1.The INTERNET permission is provided in Manifest.xml.
2.The API key is authorized.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018341/google-maps-and-unable-to-resovle-host-maps-googleapis-com

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, I checked and tested that before asking the question but it didn't solve my problem.